# Complex Equation Solving

Tags: complex-numbers

I just started learning the basics of complex numbers and complex equation, and I'll be very glad if someone can help me to solve this equation:

$$    (39w - 12\overline{w})^4 = -1$$

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you start by finding the fourth roots of $-1$? Then $39w-12\overline{w}$ is equal to four possible numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the four fourth roots of $-1$. Now $-1 = e^{i\pi(2k+1)}$, so $(-1)^{\frac 14} = e^{i\pi \frac{2k+1}{4}}$ where $k$ can take on values $0,1,2,3$ to give unique roots.

Putting the four values in Cartesian form (drawing them on an Argand diagram will help), we get all combinations of $\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ for each of the real and imaginary parts of the RHS.

Now if we let $w = a + bi$ (meaning $\overline w = a-bi$), the LHS is simply $39a - 12a + i(39b + 12b) = 27a + i51b$. All you need to do is equate the real and imaginary parts of the LHS and the RHS in turn to find all possible values of $a$ and $b$ and hence all possible values of $w$.

So $a = \pm \frac{1}{27\sqrt 2}$ and $b = \pm \frac{1}{51\sqrt 2}$ and all you need to do is write out the $4$ combinations that $w$ can take based on that.